# Laplace Transform with Piecewise...

Tags: laplace-transform

I've been having a hard time with Laplace. Did I find $Y(s)$ correctly? 
$$
y'+2y = f(t), \quad f(t) = \begin{cases}0,\;&0\le t<3,\\ 4,\;&3\le t. \end{cases}
$$
where $y(0) = 1$

the attempt:

$$
g(t) = 0, h(t) =4, a=3
$$

$$
f(t) = 4u(t-3)
$$
$$
y'+2y=4u(t-3)
$$
$$
sY(s)+sY(0)+2Y(s) = \frac 4{s}e^{-3s}
$$
isolate $Y(s)$ to get
$$
Y(s) = \frac {4e^{-3s}}{s(s+2)}-\frac 1{s+2}
$$

however, I am unsure if I did the steps correctly. I'm also new here so I really have a hard time typing this all out :(

Comment: Should be $-y(0)$ not $+Y(0)$. Now do partial fractions on $\frac{1}{s(s+2)}$. Multiplied by $e^{-3s}$ these gives time shifted terms of things in your Laplace table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing just fine with the typing! You'll get better as you get more used to it. You can check your work in the Wolfram Dev Platform by executing the command `Solve[LaplaceTransform[y'[t]+2y[t]==4 UnitStep[t-3],t,s],LaplaceTransform[y[t],t,s]]`, which yields 
$$\mathcal{L}\{y\}=\dfrac{e^{-3s}(4+e^{3s}\,s\,y(0))}{s(s+2)}.$$ You can then check your fraction decomposition by using the `Apart` function to get $$\mathcal{L}\{y\}=\dfrac{4e^{-3s}}{s(s+2)}+\dfrac{y(0)}{s+2},$$ which differs from your answer by a sign, I believe.

Don't forget that $\mathcal{L}\{y'(t)\}=s\mathcal{L}\{y\}-y(0)$.